# if condition for .datepicker attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker and i want defaultDate attribute, if it will satisfy my condition. Here is a code below,

```
 $(function () {
                jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
                  <% if (parseInt(location.search.indexOf('did=')) >= 0) { %>
                        defaultDate: getDefaultDateVal(),
                   <% } %>
                   //     defaultDate: parseInt(location.search.indexOf('did=')) >= 0 ? getDefaultDateVal() : new Date(),
                        inline: true,
                        maxDate: '+10D',
                        onLoad:function(){alert("hello");},
                        onSelect: function(date) {
                            //alert('Diet plan for ' + date);
                        var d = new Date("January 01, 1970 00:00:00");
                        var d2 = new Date(date);
                        d.setMonth(d.getMonth());
                        var theMonth;
                        theMonth = d.toString();
                        theMonth = theMonth.substr(4, 3);

                        d2.setMonth(d2.getMonth());
                        var theMonth2;
                        theMonth2 = d2.toString();
                        theMonth2 = theMonth2.substr(4, 3);

                        var firstDay = d.getDate();
                        var secondDay = d2.getDate();
                        var firstMonth = theMonth;
                        var secondMonth = theMonth2;
                        var firstYear = d.getFullYear();
                        var secondYear = d2.getFullYear();
                        var firstDate = new Date(firstDay + " " + firstMonth + " " + firstYear);
                        var secondDate = new Date(secondDay + " " + secondMonth + " " + secondYear);
                        var daysDiff = (secondDate.valueOf() - firstDate.valueOf());
                        daysDiff = Math.floor(Math.abs((((daysDiff / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24));
                        //alert(daysDiff);


                        self.location.href = './Goal.aspx?did=' + daysDiff + '';
                        //filterGetMidHead(date);
                        //wait(500);

                        //   alert(date);
                        var startdate = ((d2.getDate()).toString().length == 1) ? "0" + (d2.getDate()).toString() : (d2.getDate()).toString();
                        var enddate = new Date();
                        enddate.setDate(d2.getDate() + 7);
                        var enddate1 = ((enddate.getDate()).toString().length == 1) ? "0" + (enddate.getDate()).toString() : (enddate.getDate()).toString();
                        //  alert(enddate1 + "hello");
                        var month2 = ((d2.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1) ? "0" + (d2.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (d2.getMonth() + 1).toString();
                        var endatemonth = ((enddate.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1) ? "0" + (enddate.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (enddate.getMonth() + 1).toString();

                        //alert(new Date().setDate(d2.getDate() + 7));
                        document.getElementById('<%=lblHeaderDate1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = startdate + "/" + month2 + "/" + d2.getFullYear();
                        document.getElementById('<%=lblHeaderDate2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = enddate1 + "/" + endatemonth + "/" + enddate.getFullYear();
                        //    testnew();
                    }
                });

                  <% if (Convert.ToString(Session["LanguageID"])=="IS") 
                       { %>
                    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker(jQuery.datepicker.regional['is']);
                    <% } %>

                //jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker(jQuery.datepicker.regional['is']);


                //hover states on the static widgets
                jQuery('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                        function () { jQuery(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
                        function () { jQuery(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                    );
            });
```

But it is showing me an error. Can anyone help me how to write if condition to set datepicker attribue in 
`$("defaultDate: parseInt(location.search.indexOf('did=')) >= 0 ? getDefaultDateVal() : new Date(),").datepicker`?

Comment: "There are too many characters"...on if condition statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do?

```
<% if (parseInt(location.search.indexOf('did=')) >= 0) { %>
                    defaultDate: getDefaultDateVal(),
<% } %>
```

`parseInt` shows javascript but `<%` shows a server side code block of asp

Why don't you do it in only server side? try this

```
<% if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("did=")) { %>
                    defaultDate: getDefaultDateVal(),
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to get the `getDefaultDateVal()` function in your code. but hope this will be there in your code anywhere. So Try the below code:

```
defaultDate: ((parseInt(location.search.indexOf('did=')) >= 0) ? getDefaultDateVal() : new Date()),
```

Comment: It is also showing me an error "Too many characters in character literal"

Comment: I am not able to write if condition inside $("datepicker").datepicker({.... function. That's why it is showing me an error.

Comment: @KomalJariwala well komal, I am updating my answer check that.

Comment: But this new Date() will display only 13 days in my datepicker and other days are showing disabled in datepicker.

"I don't want to set defaultdate attribute if my condition is not satisfied."

Comment: @KomalJariwala Komal not, getting what you want can explain it in more details.

Comment: @KomalJariwala come on chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31098/room-for-gaurav-vashishtha-and-komaljariwala. so that I can you much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are writing inline javascript, because you are writing c# code inside javascript, and you are making conditions according to session ID. It's bad practice i think, because your javascript wouldn't be cached and you are mixing client- and server-side code. 
I suggest to make two different javascript file, and include to the page from c# code into a literal. In this case the If statement can be inside Page_Load, and the javascript inside a separated file.

In this Case the browser can cache it.

example:

Put this tag into aspx:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lscript"/>
```

c# page load:

```
if (Session["LanguageID"].ToString()=="IS") 
{
   lscript.Text = "<script src=/js/CondFirst.js></script>";
}
else
{
   lscript.Text = "<script src=/js/CondSecond.js></script>";
}
```

And you have to register this assembly to use literal:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Comment: I am not asking about including file. I am asking how to write if condition inside .datepicker fucntion.

Comment: I see, but i think it's better approach, and maybe helps to solve your problem too.